# Force.com rest API works in with sharing mode is there a way that we can run in without sharing mode

Tags: rest-api

Is there any way, using force.com REST API can we bypass the permissions(Objects and fields like without sharing context)

Comment: how do you know its running in with sharing?

Answer (score 2):

No, that would be a security vulnerability. The REST API respects the organization's field and record level security rules. These rules are set by the admin. In your own apex code, you can violate these rules if you have permission to load and run Apex code (author apex, given to you by the admin). But author apex is not required to use the REST/SOAP API. The API is meant to support use by regular users and so it must respect CRUD/FLS as well as sharing.

However you can write your own Apex Rest API and then perform operations that bypass the organization's security rules in apex code that handles the requests.

Even with this approach, I would recommend only ignoring sharing/FLS for fields that you own (e.g. custom fields that you create and manage). For managed packages on the Appexchange this is a requirement, but it's a best practice in general.